# How to configure WebStorm to point to VM node interpreter

Tags: node.js, vagrant, webstorm

The JetBrains Vagrant plugin applied to WebStorm handles the starting and stopping of the VM just fine.  My project node interpreter is configured on the VM.  When configuring the project settings in WebStorm only local node interpreters are available.

I am able to ssh into the VM and work with the node project from the command line, like always, but I would really like to integrate the IDE, as otherwise it is just a test editor / terminal multiplexer, and I actually don't need it.

Is there something I am missing?  On other Jetbrains products, ie PyCharm,  the user is able to select the python interpreter from a vagrant vm, but it appears this is lacking on WebStorm.

Comment: That's remote debugging, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, once I have my server running inside the VM, I can configure remote debugging.  But what about my unit tests, for example?  It's a simple thing to want to run my tests, but if my node interpreter is inside the VM, then I can't use any of the built in features of WebStorm?  That seems very restrictive to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remote Node interpreters are not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-1974](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1974) and linked tickets

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I am quite surprised that this is not already implemented.  It sounds like I am going to have to use my VM for all other services in my stack, EXCEPT node?  That is very unfortunate and I will be certainly voting on the feature request

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be supported by WebStorm yet, but there is a [workaround](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html#comment-900670787) described a comment to the official documentation.

Comment: This link is also in regards to remote debugging which is for an already running node application.  I am asking about more general integration between WebStorm and a remote node interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this now:

In your Run/Debug configuration, you can choose the Node interpreter, and more importantly, add one: press the <kbd>...</kbd> button. Then you can add a remote interpreter, either

[image]

Then you can choose which you want to use:

[image]

However, I noticed a bug. This interpreter always uploads `node_modules` (could be gigabytes) to the remote interpreter. There is no way to turn it off, even if you do **exclude** it in the settings:

[image]